# MSSQL format date and time during INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime, sql-insert

How do I format the Date and Time when inserting it into my MSSQL Query?

I know this has been asked before but I am not sure why I am having so much trouble understanding how to formatting the current date and time when INSERTING it to my database.

Originally the following INSERT Query worked but now **I want to add the current date and time with the minutes as the last characters. No seconds or Millaseconds**

```
INSERT INTO Form_Submission (ID,Submission_Date,Status)
VALUES  ('23', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Open');
```

**The formatting I am looking for is: 2015-04-08 13:42**

Comment: What format do you want the date to be? Also, are you trying to put current date?

Comment: Added example of formatting I am trying to achieve,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `LEFT` and `CONVERT` with style 120 like this

```
INSERT INTO     Form_Submission (ID,Submission_Date,Status)
 VALUES          ('23', CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,120),16)), 'Open')
```

For more details about different styles used with `Convert` refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the help and example I will trying this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert into a `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME` field then this will work:

```
CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE())
```

or `CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` if you want.

So your code is:

```
INSERT INTO     Form_Submission (ID,Submission_Date,Status)
VALUES          ('23', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE()), 'Open')
```

The point is that you are not supposed to format dates and times when inserting into the database, you should only format them on the way out (when displaying). `SMALLDATETIME` offers the level of granularity you seem to want (accurate to the nearest minute).

See MSDN documentation here: [GETDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) and [SMALLDATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182418.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `FORMAT()` T-SQL function:

```
INSERT INTO     Form_Submission (ID,Submission_Date,Status)
VALUES          ('23', FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'), 'Open')
```